# Flash Without a SWF File?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, email

Is there any way to embed Flash completely in HTML, without reference to an external SWF file? I ask because I would like to send an HTML file as an email attachment that the recipient will open in a browser and fill out as a form. The last step is that they will copy the result to their clipboard, paste it into a new message, and email it back. I cannot reliably copy to the clipboard with JavaScript because of the security issues, but there are simple Flash apps to add that capability.

I know I could just display the response text (which will be Base64 encoded) to the recipient and have them copy/paste, but it would be nice to provide this small convenience to them.

Also, so you are aware, the text is often too large to include in an email using mailto.

Yes. This needs to be done via email. The users have slow, occasional satellite email access and no other data connection to the interwebs. To make things worse, I cannot make them install anything. It is a difficult situation.

Comment: Well bear in mind that the mail reader may not be capable of running/showing Flash anyway - recall the Outlook, for example, does *not* use the IE rendering engine for HTML email.

Comment: I would just like to say... please no...

Please don't even think about trying to get this to work. It's not a convenience to the user it's a huge annoyance to your users.

Comment: @Jeremy Annoying how? I would add checks which would simply ensure that a user without flash installed would just see nothing.

Comment: I hate Flash.  Sounds like the wrong tool for the job in this case.  Sorry.

Comment: @Pointy Yeah. The users in this instance will know that they need to open the HTML in their browser. The users will have email access, but not web access, and we must be able to get them to fill out forms.

Comment: @PerterAllenWebb I'm not concerned for the person without flash. I'm concerned for the person with Flash. I would hate to open an email with embedded flash. It horrifies me to think that an email client would even include it. Email messages should not be interactive except in the reply/cc fashion they arlready are.

Comment: @Jeremy Read the question more carefully. The users will not be opening the HTML in their email client. They will be opening it in a browser.

Comment: In that case why not send just a flash app not an html webpage? then you don't have to send the html page just the flash document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always send them a PDF instead, since PDFs support interactive forms. You'd need one copy of Acrobat (or a similar tool, there are alternatives out there) and your users need free copies of Acrobat Reader. Results can be sent back as a PDF or in XML form for processing. PDF form validation is pretty advanced and can include Javascript.

Comment: This will take a lot more time for me to get up and running, but it is a valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You could try encoding the SWF in a [data: URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URI).

Comment: My thought exactly, althought I don't know if it will work with a swf.  Here's another link  http://ejohn.org/blog/embedding-and-encoding-in-javascript/

Comment: You could use a data: URL, and as far as I know that'd be the only way to do it, but data: URLs are not well supported across browsers, so look into that before you use it.

Comment: Interesting. This is new to me. I'll definitely check it out even if I don't use it.

Comment: Actually, since IE8, data: URLs are almost universally supported. Obviously IE7 cannot use them, in IE8 they aren't directly navigable (only useful for embedding small images in HTML and CSS, e.g.), and no one should be supporting IE6 at all anymore anyway. But Mozilla Gecko, WebKit and Opera (Presto) have all fully supported data: URLs for a very long time. http://a.deveria.com/caniuse/#feat=datauri

Answer (score 0):

Even if you did embed the .swf in the email as a MIME attachment or in a data url, there doesn't seem to be any way to tell the player to load the movie from that data url, e.g:

```
<object .....>
    <param name="movie" value="cid:TheEmbeddedSWFData" />
```

as you would with HTML emails with embedded images. As far as I can tell, the player expects to load the .swf using regular HTTP GET requests only. No "please send me the embedded data within email #632523462423 with CID of 'blahblahblah'".

What about compiling the .swf using [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/) or any of the [.swf-to-.exe compilers](http://www.swfkit.com/)?

That way you just attach the resulting executable, the client saves it to their machine, runs it, and the Flash application runs as a regular program, no browser required.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include Flash in emails. 90% of email systems will mark it as spam or strip it out.

Give me a link to the file or use a PDF as El Zorko said.

Comment: The users don't have Internet connections so a link wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: Then I'd say your only option is to have a email with something like first name: ... last name: ... etc